# What does the RUN command do in a Dockerfile?

Tags: linux, shell, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to decipher what the following lines of a Dockerfile do:

```
ADD MyApplication.jar app.jar
RUN (cd app.jar/MyApplication;tar -cf - src) | (cd ../..;tar -xf -) \
    && (cd app.jar/MyApplication;tar -cf - opt/att/ajsc/lib) | (cd ../..;tar -xf -) \
    && (cd app.jar/MyApplication;tar -cf - opt/att/ajsc/config) | (cd ../..;tar -xf -)
```

I think it's simply trying to extract a jar file into specific directories within the Docker image, but want to be sure.

Answer (score 5):

To quote the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run):

> The `RUN` instruction will execute any commands in a new layer on top of the current image and commit the results. The resulting committed image will be used for the next step in the `Dockerfile`.

In this specific example, your intuition is correct - the series of commands there extracts files to specific locations.

Comment: they are also grouped on the one command line so that only 1 new layer is created (vs a set of runs that would create a layer with each command.